# Find out a way to choose Most Valuable Singer

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Our student association will organize a singing competition, and everyone in my campus can choose his/her favorite singer(s) by clicking the singer(s)'s photo on web site, then students' votes(by clicking the photo) will be combined with 10 musical professionals' votes(each judge can vote either "like" or "dislike "for only one contestant ) to finally choose Most Valuable Singer this year.

Q: If I knew each contestant's click through(1+ - 40,000+) and judge scoring(0 - 10) now, so which way I can to choose?  (It is better the algorithm is described using Python)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a real question here. Be more precise. Do you want to just sort the list of a singers or you need some ranking mechanism?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question which fits StackOverflow. It isn't programming related (if I got it correctly, you are asking for a suggestion for an expression which would give weight to different vote types, not on how to program it), and you haven't shown actual research effort.

Comment: Or do you want someone to do your homework, because that's what it sounds like.

Comment: Artificial intelligence? I think you need to clarify your question a bit, if you believe there should be some AI involved in this calculation.

Answer (score 2):

First **normalize the two features** to the same scale, simple way to do it is by normalizing to [0,1] interval<sup>1</sup>:

```
students_score = (throughput-1)/40000.0
judge_score = judge/10.0
```

Now you have two normalized scores, and you need to decide how much weight each is getting, and evaluate with a **linear combination** of those:

```
final_score = a * students_score + b * judge_score
```

Where `a,b` are parameters you can tune, and `students_score ,judge_score` are the normalized results calculated above

You might also be able to chose optimal `a,b` using **[linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)** - if you are willing to manually give score to a sample of contestants

---

(1) It is sometimes better to normalize with  something dynamic like `max { throughputfor all }` for example, and not the hard absolute super limit (40000 in your case)

Comment: Well, in that case OP could simply use `a` and `b` to scale and weigh parameters simultaneously (simply a [linear combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) of these params).

Comment: @Groo: It is a good practice and more neat to first scale the features, for example for algorithms like linear regression, which tend to give bad results when scores are not normalized - normalization almost always must take place, and it is really not very time consuming nor hard to implement.